# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver) "pie thing" file transfer/copy

Tags: window, dialog

i have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on multiple systems, and noticed that when transferring files, copying, and extracting .tar files, it all goes to the "pie thing" in the top right corner of the window/file manager, and when it completes the job, I try an click the check mark, but the item don't disappear, it would only remove items from the "pie thing" after I minimize the window or close it.

Is this a bug or should it do that? Also, is there a way to get the dialog window back instead of it going to the "pie thing" ??

Does the "pie thing" have a name so I don't have to call it "pie thing"..??

Comment: Few years back they came out with a "Hamburger thing" so your "Pie thing" seems appropriate :)

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/350011/whats-new-in-ubuntu-18.04-lts-bionic-beaver-available-now/ shows the major elements of the GNOME windowing environment used in 18.04 LTS. That may help you find the popular name for that thing-a-ma-bob.

Comment: @K7AAY Maybe I read your link to quickly but it says Unity 7 is gone (true that is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) and it says Unity 8 is gone (true that never really materialized). However I get the impression it is saying there is no Unity in 18.04 which is a falsehood because Unity 7.5 is automatically installed and it's my go-to Desktop environment in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @ WinEunuuchs2Unix i have a fresh copy of 18.04 and unity did not get installed. i know you can install it but it does not come pre-installed like it usally did with ubuntu.    unity --version tells me to install it..